# Custom function with arbitrary number of parameters using IMethodCallTranslator

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to create my own `IMethodCallTranslator` like in this article
https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/row_number-support-in-2-1/

But the code with arbitrary number of parameters no longer works in EF Core 3.1.2

```
var query = dbContext.OrderItems
    .Select(i => new
    { 
        RowNumber = EF.Functions.RowNumber(new 
        {
            i.ProductId,
            _ = EF.Functions.Descending(i.OrderId)
        })
    });
```

I see that `RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor` uses `RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor` to parse method call expression and it's parameters. But it awaits parameter expression to be constant in `GetConstantOrNull` method. And so it switches to client evaluation.

```
protected override Expression VisitNew(NewExpression node) => GetConstantOrNull(node);
```

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/release/3.1/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/Internal/RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.cs#L163

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/release/3.1/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.cs#L526

Variations with `params` and `array` doesn't work either.

One possible workaround is to create multiple methods with increasing number of parameters.

```
public static long RowNumber(this DbFunctions _, object orderBy1)
public static long RowNumber(this DbFunctions _, object orderBy1, object orderBy2)
public static long RowNumber(this DbFunctions _, object orderBy1, object orderBy2, object orderBy3)
etc.
```

But is there any way to make it work with `new {}` like it was in EF Core 2?